# Hibernate throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, configuration, tomcat7

I got this error running mvn tomcat7:run from this pom.xml When deploying an application in tomcat 7. Here my dependencies, I guess that the problem comes due to mixing versions of dependent packages.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <parent>
      <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
      <artifactId>dandelion-samples-parent</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0</version>
      <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
   </parent>

   <artifactId>datatables-jsp-ajax</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <name>Dandelion :: Samples :: Datatables :: datatables-jsp-ajax</name>

   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
      <!-- Dandelion-Datatables -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
         <artifactId>datatables-jsp</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
         <artifactId>datatables-spring3</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Spring + Jackson -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <!-- JSTL -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>jstl</groupId>
         <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Servlet -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Tiles -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
         <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Hibernate as JPA implementation -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Database drivers -->
      <!-- H2 (local) -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
         <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Logging -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
         <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Here the ../../pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
   <artifactId>dandelion-samples-parent</artifactId>
   <version>0.10.0</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>

   <name>Dandelion :: Samples :: Parent</name>
   <description>Parent of all Dandelion samples</description>

   <modules>
      <module>dandelion/dandelion-jsp-starter</module>
      <module>dandelion/dandelion-thymeleaf-starter</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-jsp-starter</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-jsp-themes</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-jsp-plugins</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-jsp-configuration-groups</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-jsp-extension</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-jsp-ajax</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-jsp-i18n-struts1</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-jsp-i18n-struts2</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-jsp-export</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-thymeleaf-starter</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-thymeleaf-themes</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-thymeleaf-plugins</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-thymeleaf-configuration-groups</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-thymeleaf-ajax</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-thymeleaf-export</module>
      <module>datatables/datatables-thymeleaf-extension</module>
   </modules>

   <properties>
      <!-- Configuration -->
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

      <!-- Dependencies -->
      <dandelion.version>0.10.0</dandelion.version>
      <dandelion.datatables.version>0.10.0</dandelion.datatables.version>
      <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
      <tiles.version>2.2.2</tiles.version>
      <servlet-api.version>3.0.1</servlet-api.version>
      <thymeleaf.version>2.1.3.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
      <thymeleaf.layout.version>1.2.4</thymeleaf.layout.version>
      <thymeleaf.tiles2.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</thymeleaf.tiles2.version>
      <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
      <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
      <struts1.version>1.3.10</struts1.version>
      <struts2.version>2.1.8</struts2.version>
      <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
      <slf4j-api.version>1.7.5</slf4j-api.version>
      <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
      <h2.version>1.3.175</h2.version>

      <!-- Maven plugins -->
      <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
      <tomcat7-maven-plugin.version>2.0</tomcat7-maven-plugin.version>
      <jetty-maven-plugin.version>8.1.8.v20121106</jetty-maven-plugin.version>
      <spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>1.0.2.RELEASE</spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <!-- Dandelion -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>dandelion-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>dandelion-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>dandelion-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>dandelion-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>dandelion-webjars</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>dandelion-yuicompressor</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Dandelion-Datatables -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-compression-yui</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-export-poi</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-export-poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-export-itext</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-struts1</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-struts2</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Spring -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Struts 1 -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts1.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>${struts1.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-extras</artifactId>
            <version>${struts1.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Struts 2 -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- JSTL -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Servlet -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Jackson -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Thymeleaf -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-tiles2</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.tiles2.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.layout.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Tiles -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Sitemesh -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sitemesh</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
            <version>${sitemesh3.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Hibernate as JPA implementation -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Database drivers -->
         <!-- H2 (local) -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Logging -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <build>
      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
               <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                  <target>1.6</target>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Jetty 8 -->
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
               <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${jetty-maven-plugin.version}</version>
               <configuration>
                  <connectors>
                     <connector
                        implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>9090</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                     </connector>
                  </connectors>
                  <webAppConfig>
                     <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
                  </webAppConfig>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Tomcat 7 -->
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${tomcat7-maven-plugin.version}</version>
               <configuration>
                  <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
                  <port>9090</port>
                  <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Spring Boot -->
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${spring-boot-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
   </build>
</project>
```

Comment: do you know about http://mvnrepository.com/ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This class was added in the 4.x.x version and you won't find it in Hibernate 3

```
hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar\org\hibernate\internal\CoreMessageLogger.class
```

It may be that you have 2 versions of `hibernate-core` in your Maven dependency tree.

You need to:

1. run `mvn dependency:tree`
2. check how many `hibernate-core` versions you have and which other 3rd oarty dependencies are adding the `hibernate-core` on your behalf
3. exclude the transitive `hibernate-core` dependency from other external dependencies and rely only on your explicit configuration

Comment: How do I "exclude the transitive hibernate-core dependency from other external dependencies"?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a jar conflict. You have hibernate 3 and Hibernate 4 in your classpath and hibernate 3 is the first.

Answer (score 1):

I got the above error while using activity with spring boot and jpa. It is problem with hibernate core and hibernate entity manager versions. So I upgraded my spring boot version to 1.4.0RELEASE from 1.3x. And included the hibernate dependencies as follows to fix the issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the mvn dependency:tree

```
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
    [INFO] Building Dandelion :: Samples :: Datatables :: datatables-jsp-ajax 0.10.0 
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ datatables-jsp-ajax --- 
    [INFO] com.github.dandelion:datatables-jsp-ajax:war:0.10.0 
    [INFO] +- com.github.dandelion:datatables-jsp:jar:0.10.0:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- com.github.dandelion:datatables-core:jar:0.10.0:compile 
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.github.dandelion:dandelion-core:jar:0.10.0:compile 
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.1:compile 
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.1:compile 
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.1:compile 
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile 
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.10:compile 
    [INFO] |  |  |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:compile 
    [INFO] |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- com.github.dandelion:dandelion-jsp:jar:0.10.0:compile 
    [INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile 
    [INFO] +- com.github.dandelion:datatables-spring3:jar:0.10.0:compile 
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile 
    [INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile 
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile 
    [INFO] |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile 
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile 
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile 
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile 
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile 
    [INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile 
    [INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile 
    [INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile 
    [INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided 
    [INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:2.2.2:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:2.2.2:compile 
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:2.2.2:compile 
    [INFO] |  |     +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile 
    [INFO] |  |     \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile 
    [INFO] |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:2.2.2:compile 
    [INFO] |     \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:2.2.2:compile 
    [INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.5.Final:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.5.Final:compile 
    [INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile 
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile 
    [INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.4.Final:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile 
    [INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile 
    [INFO] |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile 
    [INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.175:compile 
    [INFO] \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile 
    [INFO]    \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile 
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS 
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
    [INFO] Total time: 3.576 s 
    [INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-28T20:58:20+01:00
```